# Scrabble Python regular expression matching

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

I am attempting to create a simple scrabble solver program that can create a list of all 3 letter words in the Python words corpus dictionary. I have had a read up on searching for regular expressions in python, however have not yet been able to come up with a solution for my problem.

I am a beginner to python, so this may be a very easy fix or program, but any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my expression, which is meant to return every 3 letter word consisting of only vowels within the dictionary, however it is currently returning every word in the dictionary that contains a vowel! I have a feeling it may be to do with my metacharacters but am unsure.

```
vowels = [w for w in words if re.search('aeiou$', w)]
```

Comment: *"it is currently returning every word in the dictionary that contains a vowel"* - nope, that regex will match only words that literally end with `'aeiou'`. *"every 3 letter word consisting of only vowels"* would be `r'^[aeiou]{3}$'`. You should try reading a regex tutorial.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My mistake, I should have left out the $ metacharacter. Can you offer any guidance on how to get to my desired output?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store all 3 letter words, consisting only of vowels:

```
import re

words = ['asd', 'aei', 'a']
result = [w for w in words if re.match(r'[aeiou]{3}$', w)]

print(result)
```

`[asd]` would match either `'a'`, `'s'` or `'d'`. `{3}` would match exactly 3 of those. [`match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) matches the beginning of the string.

---

Alternatively, if you want to avoid regular expressions:

```
results = []
for w in words:
    if len(w) == 3:

        for letter in w:
            if letter not in 'aeiou':
                break
        else:
            results.append(w)
```

If a non vowel is found, `for` breaks and its `else:` is not reached, so the word is not stored.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your regex produced the exact output i was after. As a side note, is it possible to easily edit to regex, to now say match all words with a maximum length of 3 characters? I tried simple adding a < before the 4, however to no avail. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @freshwaterjoe Yes. To do that simply change `{3}` to `{4}`. In the link i provided, you can scroll up and read more about symbols used in patterns and their meaning. Offtopic: It would be nice, if you edit your question and change the inaccurate part that @john mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use anchors, add the `y` letter that also can be a vowel, and `[aeiouy]` character class:

```
   result = [w for w in words if re.match(r'^[aeiouy]{3}$', w)]
```

If 'y' is yielding unwanted results, you can remove the `y` letter from the character class.

```
   result = [w for w in words if re.match(r'^[aeiou]{3}$', w)]
```